# Could not resolve argument .. maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"?

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I keep getting this error when adding controller to my symphony bundle:

> Could not resolve argument $returnController of "verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Controller\Crop\CropController::crop()", maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"?

This is the controller (src/Controller/Crop/CropController.php):

```
namespace verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Controller\Crop;

class CropController
{

/** @var ImageService */
private $imageService;

public function __construct(ImageService $imageService)
{
    $this->imageService = $imageService;
}

public function crop($returnController,Request $request)
{....
```

Service yaml file (src/Resources/config/services.yaml):

```
UploadImagesBundle\Controller\Crop:
resource: '../../src/Controller/Crop'
tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

UploadImagesExtension file (src/DependencyInjection/UploadImagesExtension.php):

```
...
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new 
FileLocator(dirname(__DIR__).'/Resources'));
```

Comment: Is `$returnController` a request argument or something?  In any event, use `bin/console debug:container CropController` to verify you have a properly tagged CropController service defined.  If not then post the defaults section of your service.yaml file after confirming it is being loaded.  In most cases you would manually define a bundle's services but autowire will work when properly setup.

Comment: I removed the $returnController and averything was okay! Just misread it! Thanks!